# Ajax CallBack has a lack of time to be triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I have a problem with Firefox and I need to find out why the reason is for this behavior because it's a problem in a production environment.

The situation is that I need to send an asynchronous request, by `JQuery.ajax` and most of the time it works fine, but there are some cases where the response has a lack of time to be delivered to the callback function, although the response has been sent by the server in the same second, as you can see in these logs and the code where you can match each message from the log, and the sniffer capture to see the times of the request:

1. **15:00:00** he request is going to be sent.
   1.1. Information of the request before the moment or being triggered.
2. **15:00:05** The Request's response is delivered but has arrived 5 seconds later than the response registered on the sniffer, as you can see further.

```
// 1.
15:00:00 [iframe.webservices.webservicesScheduleGet] time1=00:00:01, time2=23:59:59 utils.js:10:10

// 1.1
[api.webservices.invoke] (schedule): webservices.js:26:11
[api.webservices.invoke] method=Get webservices.js:27:11
[api.webservices.invoke] params=ini=00:00:01&fin=23:59:59 webservices.js:28:11
[api.webservices.invoke] expecting=text webservices.js:29:11
Este sitio usa el certificado SHA-1; se recomienda que uses los certificados con algoritmos de firma que utilicen las funciones hash más fuertes que SHA-1. Get

// 2
[api.webservices.invoke] (schedule) on complete webservices.js:40:13
[api.webservices.invoke] status=200 (OK) webservices.js:41:13
15:00:05 [iframe.webservices.webservicesScheduleGetComplete] text=True utils.js:10:10
15:00:05 [iframe.messages.messagesScheduleCheck] message=[{"M_TYPE":113,"RESULT":"true"}] utils.js:10:10
```

This is the code:

```js
function webservicesScheduleGet(time1, time2)
{
    consoleLog("[iframe.webservices.webservicesScheduleGet] time1=" + time1 + ", time2=" + time2);

    if (webservicesAvoidRequest())
        return;

    var method = "Get";
    var params = "ini=" + time1 + "&fin=" + time2;
    scheduleWebService.invoke(method, params, webservicesScheduleGetComplete, webservicesScheduleOnError, "text");
}

function WebServices ()
{
    //...
    this.invoke = function (method, params, onComplete, onError, dataType)
    {
        if (this.wsName === null)
        {
            console.warn("[api.webservices.invoke] the webservice is not initialized yet");
            return;
        }

        console.log("[api.webservices.invoke] (" + this.wsName + "):");
        console.log("[api.webservices.invoke] method=" + method);
        console.log("[api.webservices.invoke] params=" + params);
        console.log("[api.webservices.invoke] expecting=" + dataType);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: this.remoteUrl + "/" + method,
            data: params,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: dataType,
            context: this,
            complete: function (response)
            {
                console.log("[api.webservices.invoke] (" + this.wsName + ") on complete");
                console.log("[api.webservices.invoke] status=" + response.status + " (" + response.statusText + ")");
                if (response.status !== 200)
                {
                    console.warn("[api.webservices.invoke] error in response: status=" + response.status);
                    return;
                }
                onComplete(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response)
            {
                console.warn("[api.webservices.invoke] (" + this.wsName + ") on error");
                console.warn("[api.webservices.invoke] error in response: text=" + response.responseText);
                onError();
            }
        });
    };
};

function webservicesScheduleGetComplete(text)
{
    consoleLog("[iframe.webservices.webservicesScheduleGetComplete] text=" + text);
    
    messagesScheduleCheck(text.toLowerCase());
}
```

The sniffer shows that the time between request and response is less than 1 second but it (response) was delivered to the callback 5 seconds later. The IP of the workstation is **172.29.150.9** and the Ip of the server is **172.31.101.83**.

[image]

It's important to consider that this script is part of a solution that is embedded into another main product, a front end of the agent, which makes another Asynchronous request by ajax, but not at the same time that this.

- The Operating System is Windows 7 Professional 64 bits.
- The browser is Firefox 72.0.1 a 64bits.
- The processor is Intel Core i3-6100 CPU @3.70GHz.
- The memory ram is 8Gb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see 2 outgoing messages from the workstation to the server, separated by 9 seconds, probably the delay you noticed in the ajax hander. It looks like the server didn't respond to the first request, so it was re-sent. Notice the client-sequence 1206 on packet 35405, followed by a repeated client-sequence 1205 on packet 38821. It looks like a packet was dropped on the way to the server. This can happen because of line noise maybe?

Comment: I don't think so, those are Keep-Alive messages, which are sent because the browser uses persistent connections. Also, Package 35405 is the Ack of the workstation which means that the response has been received. For those reasons, I don't think that response (Package 35359) had been retransmitted.